# How to list more than 1000 objects with S3 ListBucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am working with the Amazon S3 API, specifically with ListObjects (v2), the GetBucket command.  Frustratingly, I can only get back 1000 objects.  I think that you specify a Delimeter or nextMarker is set to induce pagination and get back everything.  Anyone have an example of how this is accomplished?  The final result from curl or a GET is actually getting all the things back, not just 1000 objects.

Answer (score 7):

If the `list_objects()` response has `IsTruncated` set to True, then you can make a subsequent call, passing `NextContinuationToken` from the previous response to the `ContinuationToken` field on the subsequent call. This will return the next 1000 objects.

Or, you can use the provided Paginators to do this for you.

From [Paginators — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html):

```py
import boto3

# Create a client
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')

# Create a reusable Paginator
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

# Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket')

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the StartAfter parameter which is the full key name. If you create your own loop you can just take the last key you processed and update the StartAfter param, then fetch a new batch of 1000 starting at that key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#v2-RESTBucketGET-requests

Here is a node JS example for how to process millions of objects. It asynchronously processes 200 at a time in batches of 1000. But skipped the processing part here.

```js
    let startPos = null
    while(1) {
        const fetchParam = {
          Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
          MaxKeys: 1000 // can be less too
        }
        if (startPos) {
          fetchParam.StartAfter = startPos
        }
        // Get all objects in the s3 bucket
        const objects = await s3.listObjectsV2(fetchParam).promise()
        // Divide the objects into groups of 200
        const objectGroups = objects.Contents.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => 
        {
          const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / 200)
    
          if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
            resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // start a new chunk
          }
    
          resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)
    
          return resultArray
        }, [])
    
        // End the loop when there are no more objects
        if (objects.Contents.length === 0) {
          break
        }
    
        // Do stuff with the objectGroups (preferably async) and update the startPos
        startPos = 'latest-processed-key'
    }
```